# How do I use the KDE 5 monitor calibration tool?

Tags: monitors, kde5

I recently replace my laptop monitor and have noticed it's not as crisp as the only one / my external monitors.  In KDE5 there is a "System Settings Module" called `Gamma` that supplies different test pictures and some sliders to set overall gamma or individual color settings.

Unfortunately, there's no directions on how to use this.  I've tried searching for the app's homepage, but "gamma", "linux gamma", "kde gamma", and "ubuntu gamma" all just return a ton of irrelevant results, as one might expect.

I tried using xprop to find the proper program name via mouse click: `xprop |awk '/WM_CLASS/{print $3}`
but it returned `"kcmshell5"` which is just the generic KDE settings manager.

**What is the proper name, and where is the man page for this program?**

and/or

**How do I use it to calibrate my monitor?**

[image]

---

Linux Mint 18.2

KDE Plasma Version 5.8.9

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [docs here](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kgamma5/kcontrol/kgamma5/).

As you said, it's a system setting module, not a program: it doesn't have a man page. The module is installed with the kgamma5 package.

```
apt search kgamma

kgamma5/bionic-updates,now 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
monitor calibration panel for KDE
```